# Unable to start a micro front-end app in single-SPA application

Tags: npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server, single-spa

I am facing error while trying to start sub-app in Single-SPA application. Basically, I am trying to develop a kind of util app (sub app in Single-SPA) which contains Sockjs, Stomp-client etc. I have removed node modules and package-lock.json and installed node modules again. When I try to start application I am facing below error.

```
Error:
[webpack-cli] Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'firewall'. These properties are valid:
   object { allowedHosts?, bonjour?, client?, compress?, devMiddleware?, headers?, historyApiFallback?, host?, hot?, http2?, https?, ipc?, liveReload?, onAfterSetupMiddleware?, onBeforeSetupMiddleware?, onListening?, open?, port?, proxy?, setupExitSignals?, static?, watchFiles?, webSocketServer? }
 - options.client has an unknown property 'host'. These properties are valid:
   object { logging?, overlay?, progress?, webSocketTransport?, webSocketURL? }
```

Command used for running the app : `npm start`

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "@sudeep/livedoc",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve",
    "start:standalone": "webpack serve --env standalone",
    "build": "webpack --mode=production",
    "analyze": "webpack --mode=production --env analyze",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext js,ts,tsx",
    "format": "prettier --write .",
    "check-format": "prettier --check .",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "test": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=test jest --passWithNoTests",
    "watch-tests": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=test jest --watch",
    "coverage": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=test jest --coverage"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.6",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.14.7",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.7",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.14.6",
    "babel-jest": "^27.0.5",
    "concurrently": "^6.2.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "eslint": "^7.29.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-config-ts-important-stuff": "^1.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "husky": "^6.0.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^27.0.5",
    "jest-cli": "^27.0.5",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "pretty-quick": "^3.1.1",
    "ts-config-single-spa": "^2.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.3.4",
    "webpack": "^5.40.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2",
    "webpack-config-single-spa": "^4.0.0",
    "webpack-config-single-spa-ts": "^2.2.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/systemjs": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.16.0",
    "fast-json-patch": "3.0.0-1",
    "rxjs": "6.6.0",
    "stompjs": "2.3.3",
    "sockjs-client": "1.5.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did one of the answers help you?

Answer (score 12):

I resolved this problem by updating "webpack-config-single-spa-ts" from 2.0.0 to 3.0.0.

Answer (score 6):

The `firewall` option has been [renamed](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/pull/3345) as of [webpack-dev-server v4.0.0-rc.0](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/releases/tag/v4.0.0-rc.0)

You should use `allowedHosts` instead of `firewall`.

This problem has been [fixed](https://github.com/single-spa/create-single-spa/pull/310) in version 4.0.0 of [webpack-config-single-spa](https://github.com/single-spa/create-single-spa/blob/main/packages/webpack-config-single-spa/CHANGELOG.md)
, so upgrading this package will fix your issue as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation in React.
The package.json file for the project had:

```
"webpack-config-single-spa-react": "2.0.0",
```

Therefore, when I executed

```
npm i
```

npm installed the exact required version of this component (2.0.0). It is possible to verify the installed version, if you look under

```
./node_modules/webpack-config-single-spa-react/package.json
```

I manually deleted the folder webpack-config-single-spa-react.
Edited the package.json in my project to request a version above 3.0.0:

```
"webpack-config-single-spa-react": "^3.0.0",
```

executed "npm install"

verified that at least version 3.0.0 of the package was installed by looking at:

```
./node_modules/webpack-config-single-spa-react/package.json
```

The actions above resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Modify in your **package.json** this module **webpack-dev-server** to **4.0.0-beta.0** and rebuild.

My versions:
[packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mGuk.png)

Comment: `^v4.0.0-beta.0` means it can be upgraded to `v4.0.0-rc.0`, so this answer will not work.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots when sharing text.